# How do I add the whole css to a django form?

Tags: python, html, css, django

This is the forms.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import  forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': ''}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': ''}),
            'password': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': ''})
    }
```

I want to add css to my form that is something like this :

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_ul}}
<div class="send">
  <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" class="register" />
</div>
```

I know how to add css classes but the biggest part of the css attributes are set on the whole file like this :

```
.send input {
  width: 27%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #0889c4;
  border: 3px solid #0889c4;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And I don't know how to make django take those as valid css attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can put as many css attributes you want for any individual field of form using `attrs={'style':'width:150px;height:80px;','placeholder':'Some Text'}` and all. If you want to apply same css to a group of fields defined in your form than what you can do is, apply that css class to a `<div>` in your html file/template and put the elements/fields of your form inside that div. It should work.